# How to replace the keyless unlock button?

Tags: nissan, replace, altima, keyless-entry, replacements

My keyless unlock button on my 2009 Nissan Altima no longer works, and I'd like to replace it. I'm not sure if that's the correct term, because I can't seem to find the part anywhere, or instructions on how to replace it.  Do I have to replace the entire handle?

[image: 2009 Nissan Door Handle]

Comment: Have you asked the parts department at a good dealer? They will have a detailed parts list...

Comment: I actually haven't yet.  Lol.  My general method is to save the dealership to the last resort, but I guess this might be a time to make an exception.

Comment: That being said, my main question is how to replace it, which they may or may not be able to help with.  If I don't end up getting an answer here by the time I figure it out, I'll take some pictures and post.

Comment: Once you have a part number, then it might make getting instructions easier - perhaps I was lucky the dealers always provided info to me...

Answer (score 1):

I *believe* you can just change the switch. In what I've found, it's called *Outside Door Handle Passive Entry Switch*. The outside door handles either have the hole or not, but don't come with the switch. There are two parts to the door handle, so it would have to come off, then the door handle separated to get at the switch. Here's what the parts look like when taken apart:

[image]

To remove the door handle itself, you need to pop the plug on the inner door jam, then with a T30 Torx bit, remove the bolt holding the handle in place. Here's an image of what you're looking at:

[image]

Once the bolt is pulled all the way to the rear, you should be to pull the back part of the door handle (the non-moving part) off, then the moving part will come loose. Don't worry about the Torx bolt, it should be captured in that part of the door handle. I'm sure it will become self evident after you get the handle off what you'd need to do with the switch and how to replace it. I'm also pretty sure you're most likely going to need to go to the Stealership in order to find a replacement switch.

Comment: Just got around to doing it.  Had to order an entire handle from the dealer -- they don't sell just the button.  You have to take out that torx bolt, but also have to remove the interior door panel, and the metal window cover (make sure the window is rolled up) to get to the wire connector.  Need a 10mm and a Phillips. Feel free to add that in.